# php truncate if screen is smaller then

Tags: php, truncate, responsive

I have a breadcrumb in my website, but I want to truncate it when the screen is smaller than 480px. I am using the mb_strimwidth() function, but how do I detect if the screen is smaller than 480px with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot retrieve the screen size in PHP.

You can however retrieve the screen-size using JavaScript, send it to PHP and store it somewhere for future reference (like in the database or a cookie) and then use that data to truncate.

If you use jQuery you can use `.height` and `.width` on `$(document)` or `$(window)` to get the size of the browser and the document.

Comment: Okay, that's a shame. I will try the javascript - php combination. Thanks for the fast answer! :)